# Environment management Node.js plugins/methods for Heroku apps?

Tags: node.js, heroku, workflow, environment-variables, development-environment

It seems that my workflow would be improved if I had some way to automatically manage my environment variables so I can have different sets load automatically depending on if the server is running locally or running on Heroku.

What are my choices? Heroku must be using something on their end, because there are variable like local.env.PORT. What are they using? I was thinking that maybe if I use the same thing it would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the [Foreman ruby gem](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) with Heroku even if you are deploying apps using Node.js.

Foreman allows you to specify different application configurations on your local and remote application servers. I use it to control and manage my workers, web instances on Heroku for my rails apps.

Here's a link to a Heroku page showing how to manage environment variables using foreman:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) which is quite useful. There is a [node-figaro](https://github.com/cmanzana/node-figaro) project inspired by figaro, but the docs are unclear on how to actually use the project to initialize environment variables.